# How to mount a directory for a user that doesn't exist yet in vagrant

Tags: linux, permissions, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm trying to mount a data disk in vagrant using the shared folder mechanism, which works well except that the directory is owned by `vagrant` by default and `tomcat6` can't write to it. So I thought I could set the owner of the disk in the vagrantfile using:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "data/", "/data", owner: "tomcat6", group: "tomcat6"
```

but the `tomcat6` user doesn't exist yet as the tomcat recipe hasn't been run yet so vagrant fails with:

```
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u tomcat6`,gid=`getent group tomcat6 | cut -d: -f3` data /data
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u tomcat6`,gid=`id -g tomcat6` data /data

The error output from the last command was:

stdin: is not a tty
id: tomcat6: no such user
id: tomcat6: no such user
uid= requires an argument (i.e. uid==<arg>)
```

Now I can work round this by mounting /data with world write permission but that seems "wrong" to me (even on a test machine).

So is there any way to make vagrant create a new user for me before I mount the disk or to have Chef provision me a shared disk later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch to the `nfs` sync provider as that supports remote files with unknown UIDs. See https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html for details.

Comment: You do need to set no_root_squash in /etc/exports on the host machine to allow vagrant to change the owner later

Answer (score 2):

A workaround I've used for my own VMs has been to force Vagrant to re-run the initial setup after running provisioning:

```
vagrant up  # this fails at synced_folder; put that at the end of Vagrantfile
vagrant provision  # this creates the user
vagrant halt  # shut down
vagrant up  # re-runs the synced_folder command, this time the user exists
```

It's not graceful, but stick it in a bash script and it'll prop up a working VM.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the UID/GID of the future user will be, you can simply provide those values instead of the user/group names. e.g. if 'tomcat6' has GID/GID of 11111, you could state in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "data/", "/data", owner: "11111", group: "11111"
```

Comment: Worth noting that even when you think you know the UID/GID, it can sometimes change when the box updates. I was bitten by this - my VM had a vboxsf user, but somebody else's didn't, so the "mounting" user got a different UID/GID. GDorn's workaround could be a better option where nfs isn't available